# Kendo UI Export Excel with format

Tags: javascript, html, excel, kendo-ui, format

I'm using Kendo UI to export my data to an Excel Workbook.
But I can't figure out how to get the format to work. This is an dojo example where I've reproduced the problem.

http://dojo.telerik.com/OGETa/3

It doesn't seem to accept the format until you've double clicked the cell and pressed enter (or left it again).

I want to be able to write a =sum(B1:B2) in the B3 cell after I've exported the document, but it will not accept the values B1 and B2 right away as [hh]:mm.

Comment: What answer are you getting from the formula? What answer do you expect?

Comment: =sum(B1:B2) in B3 cell just gives 00:00. I would have expected to see 37:00. And it does so if I go into B1 cell and B2 cell (i.e. just double click and press enter).
.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution for?